# Swift: Gesture Recognizer doesn't register Taps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm having a little trouble getting my UITapGestureRecognizer to register touches from the user. The ***showMenu()*** function is supposed to display a partially transparent *blackView* to the user, and I've implemented the gesture recognizer so that when the user taps on *blackView*, ***dismiss()*** is called and makes the view fade.

In my XCode Console, I don't receive the print message "dismissed" as designated in the code.

Thanks in advance!

```
func showMenu(){
    print("show")

    if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow{

        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)

        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismiss)))

        window.addSubview(blackView)
        blackView.frame = window.frame
        blackView.alpha = 0

        //Added this line 
        blackView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5){
            self.blackView.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}

func dismiss(){
    print("dismiss")

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5){
        self.blackView.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I've checked to see if any views were on top stealing the taps using the View Hierarchy Debug tool but there doesn't seem to be anything above *blackView*, I've also explicitly set *blackView* to allow User Interaction.

**EDIT:** A screenshot of the View Hierarchy Debug interface.

[image]

Comment: have you tried to set the numberOfTapsRequired to 1?

Comment: @Scriptable, just did. Unfortunately, I'm receiving the same results.

Comment: Hmm, ok, the code looks ok to me, could you try bringing the subview to the front? `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(blackView)` after adding the subView, see if that helps. I'm unable to test it at the minute, just coming up with ideas

Comment: I believe *blackView* is already upfront. I've edited my question with images showing the View Hierarchy Debug screen.

Comment: You weren't clear on whether or not blackView ever got presented.

Comment: Try using `self.dismiss` in your #selector. And use the autocomplete.

Comment: @andrewcar, I can confirm *blackView* was presented, because the showResult() function is initially triggered by a button. And *blackView* does show.

Comment: @jose920405 adding `self.` in action will not change nothing. Object to perform action already declared in `target`

Comment: Try moving the addGestureRecognizer line to the end of the showMenu() function.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the alpha view to zero it stops getting touch events.

You could try to change view's background color to transparent, instead of changing view's alpha, that way your view won't be visible and you get the events

Comment: Is it possible to animate the transparency transition?

Comment: Instead of self.blackView.alpha = 0 put in your UIView.animateWithDuration  self.blackView.backgroundColor = <your color>

Comment: Alright. But in my code, when I'm supposed to touch *blackView*, the alpha values are technically set to 1 as it's displayed. I don't believe the root issue is with alpha values, what else could've gone wrong?

Comment: As I said , in the time you set alpha to 0 gesture STOP to work, there isnt any restart.

Comment: Sorry, but I think there's been a misinterpretation. I'm trying to get the gestureRecognizer to call the dismiss() function, but the alpha values are initially set to 1 because of the animation snippet in the showMenu() function.

Comment: @BlackDeveraux did you try at least blackView.alpha = 0.01 instead this discussion??

Comment: @ShadowOf Yes, I have :)

Comment: @ShadowOf every discussion is acceptable to solve the problem , your arrogance is rather unwelcome

Comment: @BlackDeveraux I take my words back. Your code works for me without any changes, as you posted it in question. So, this answer is wrong, view keeps its gestures with any alpha value (view just can not receive events with alpha = 0). Since your code you posted works well in standard view controller, you need search problem in other places

Comment: @ShadowOf This answer is not wrong , it said blackView  can not receive events with alpha = 0 : Apple official docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:  (hit test part), OP use alpha = 0 so he's stopped UITapGestureRecognizer, the animation doesnt affect.

Comment: > the animation doesnt affect - this is wrong. After animation is complete, alpha have nonzero value and view again can receive events. So, your answer is not really answering question.

Comment: @ShadowOf I think you don't know how the responder chain work. You must read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW2

"Touch events. If the hit-test view cannot handle a touch event, the event is passed up a chain of responders that starts with the hit-test view."

Comment: When I set .alpha = 1 after alpha was zero, my view again can handle touch event. If I wrong, explain me please, why OP code works in my view controller without any changes.

Comment: @ShadowOf is correct in the fact that the Alpha value is restored to 1 allowing for Touch Events to be registered. I probably have misconfigured some of my code elsewhere, but I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code. It recognises if there has been 1 touch and then you can call your dismiss method.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first?.tapCount
    if touch == 1 {
        // Call Dismiss
        dismiss()
    }
}
```